# Is there any way to move the negative to the left side on DataPrep?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I have this DataFrame which was exported from SAP, and it comes with the negative numbers like these

```
   a   b   c
0  1   2-  3-
1  4-  5   6
2  7   8-  9-
```

Is there any way to move the (-) sign to the left side on Google Cloud DataPrep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few ways of doing that, let's cover a simple one -

1. Using *find-replace* transformation, with *grouping* :
   [image: List item]
   {number} is Trifacta pattern for any kind of number (int\dec)

   ({number}) saves this pattern as "group 1", later reference at the "replace" field.

   We're just deleting the suffix "-", and adding one of our own at the beginning.

   Notice that by "trying to find the minus suffix" we're making sure we're not adding a minus where it's not needed.